# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, advertising, site-promotion

This is one of [**The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).  What are we going to do to promote this site?  Answers should address one or more means of spreading the word so that we attract the best and brightest minds in the ebook world as regular contributors.

Some avenues that come to mind:

- Word of mouth (i.e., through existing personal contacts), which we all should be doing:

  - Literally -- tell your friends
  - Email (not bulk, but specific to people you already know who may have an interest in this area)
  - Personal blogs
  - Twitter
  - Facebook
  - Pinterest (I have little experience with it, personally, so maybe this one's no good)
  - LinkedIn
- Interest groups:

  - Ebook-related forums on the web -- **help us identify these!**
  - Ebook-related blogs -- **help us identify these!**
  - Ebook-related Twitter, Facebook, Pinterest, LinkedIn, etc. accounts/groups/pages -- **help us identify these!**
- Offline avenues (conventions, meetings, publications) -- **help us identify these!**
- What else?

Let's brainstorm here and get an action plan together!

Comment: I've been promoting e-books to my G+ contacts. I don't have many Twitter followers...

Answer (score 3):

There's a fairly active group of ebook creation professionals across a range of social media, but mostly active on Twitter, that uses the #eprdctn hashtag. I've reached out to them a couple of times, but more would be better. One great way to do this would be to tweet about questions here that could use their insight, using that hashtag. Just don't make it spammy, of course.

Comment: This is excellent. I think the suggestion to tweet specific questions is a great one.

Answer (score 2):

We need to create the ad that is shared across stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

[SciFi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) (and probably others) have a weekly newsletter, that you can sign up for.  They have an advertisement running on the sidelines.  We could do the same.

Get the weekly newsletter!

- Top questions and answers
- Important announcements
- Unanswered questions

Comment: Actually, I think all sites have this; they are automatically generated. I went to [http://stackexchange.com/newsletters](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) and was able to search for and subscribe to the eBooks newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

A skinnier mobile site; it will read better on ebook readers with internet.

Comment: http://stackmobile.com/ebooks ?