# Should we try and get a team to work on advertising?

Tags: discussion, advertising

We all seem to acknowledge and support the idea that we [need to do some advertising](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173).  But we are not really getting anywhere with it.  My thought is that we get two or three people to take a more active role in getting the advertising rolling.  We need someone volunteers who will take the ball and go with it.  It has been said '[There is no such thing as bad publicity](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/there-is-no-such-thing-as-bad-publicity.html)*.  Anything is better than nothing, if someone does not like where the team took it, than that is good reason for them to jump in and improve it.

If you have any desire to work on this please post an answer.